# C Rightshift not working correctly

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, lc3

I'm trying to implement a LC3 Simulator in C and while parsing the instruction codes I've run into a snag. I have a method, get_bits() which is supposed to get the bits of a specified short int (defined as 'Word').

```
Word get_bits(Word val, Word leftBit, Word rightBit){
    printf("\nWord: %x, LeftBit: %d, RightBit: %d\n", val,leftBit,rightBit);
    Word leftPad = 15 - leftBit;
    Word rightPad = leftPad + rightBit;
    printf("LeftPad: %d RightPad: %d\n", leftPad,rightPad);
    printf("Val   : "); printBinary(val);  printf("\n");
    Word temp = val << leftPad;
    printf("Temp L: "); printBinary(temp); printf("\n");    
    temp = val >> rightPad;
    printf("Temp R: "); printBinary(temp); printf("\n");    


    //build mask
   Word mask = 0x0;
   switch(leftBit - rightBit){
        case 3:
            mask = 0x000F;
            break;
        case 2:
            mask = 0x0007;
            break;
        default:
            printf("Case Not Covered!");
            break;
    }
    printf("Mask:   "); printBinary(mask); printf("\n");
    temp = temp & mask;
    return temp;    
}
```

for a given instruction, 1221, the ASM should be ADD R1, R0, 1
However, the get_bits() function fails on the second parsing. 
It correctly parses the "ADD" part, which is the first four bits, but when attempting to parse the R1 part, it right shifts one too many times and I don't understand why. The output:

```
@ 4096 (1000) Value: 4641   1221 ASM:
```

first 4 bits = "ADD", works correctly

```
Word: 1221, LeftBit: 15, RightBit: 12
LeftPad: 0 RightPad: 12
Val   : 0001001000100001
Temp L: 0001001000100001
Temp R: 0000000000000001
Mask:   0000000000001111
ADD
```

should get bits 11 - 9, the 3 bits constitute register 1 ("001"), but get shifted to 0

```
Word: 1221, LeftBit: 11, RightBit: 9
LeftPad: 4 RightPad: 13
Val   : 0001001000100001
Temp L: 0010001000010000
Temp R: 0000000000000000
Mask:   0000000000000111
```

should get bits 8 - 6, the 3 bits constitute register 0 ("000"), are read correctly

```
Word: 1221, LeftBit: 8, RightBit: 6
LeftPad: 7 RightPad: 13
Val   : 0001001000100001
Temp L: 0001000010000000
Temp R: 0000000000000000
Mask:   0000000000000111

R0, R0,
```

So why is my right shift not working for the second call, but works fine for the first and last call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your `rightPad` having also the `leftPad` in it. There is no need to add anything to the right shift amount you give to the function. Just shift right that much and it works.

Why the error doesn't occur on the first time is due to the `leftBit` being 15, so `15 - 15` is zero and you shift only the amount of `rightBit`.

So simply

```
temp = val >> rightBit;
```

Comment: But if Temp L is 0010 0010 0001 0000 and rightbit is 9, won't the new temp be: 0000 0000 0001 0001 ? It'll get me 001 with the mask but only because the second set of 3 bits is the same as the first set.

If for example the word was: 0001 001 010 1 00001 (ADD R1, R2, 1)
then wouldn't finding the set of bits go like this if using only the right bit (left: 11, right 9), we get 0000 0000 0001 0101, which will give us 101 (6) instead of 001 (1).

Comment: I tested your solution and it works, I just don't understand why

Comment: @DevanshuBharel The second set has nothing to do with it. If you shift right 9 bits, you chop off 9 bits and mask the three. It will always work as it should. Shifting 0001 001 010 1 00001 to the right nine bits will be 0001 001 and will mask to 001 as it should. Your example would be shifting only 7.

Comment: AH! I figured out where the error was. The solution I was trying to implement had to left/right shift temp, but my code was temp = val >> rightPad. 
changing it to temp = temp >> rightPad achieves the desired result as well